# PHP-FPM in Docker and concurrent requests

Tags: php, docker, nginx

There is a docker container with PHP-FPM ("php:8.0-fpm") and with Nginx that proxies to PHP:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php_container:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

In fpm config:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 16
```

docker top php:

```
PID    PPID   C   STIME   TTY   TIME         CMD
14967  14891  0   20:56   ?     00:00:00     php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
15156  14967  0   20:56   ?     00:00:00     php-fpm: pool www
15157  14967  0   20:56   ?     00:00:00     php-fpm: pool www
15158  14967  0   20:56   ?     00:00:00     php-fpm: pool www
...
... 16 items of pool www
```

docker top www:

```
UID       PID    PPID    C   STIME  TTY  TIME       CMD
root      14968  14938   0   20:56  ?    00:00:00   nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
systemd+  15207  14968   0   20:56  ?    00:00:00   nginx: worker process
systemd+  15208  14968   0   20:56  ?    00:00:00   nginx: worker process
systemd+  15209  14968   0   20:56  ?    00:00:00   nginx: worker process
...
... 12 workers
```

index.php:

```php
echo date('H:i:s').' '.getmypid().'; ';
sleep(10);
echo date('H:i:s');
exit();
```

I just open a number of tabs in a browser at the same time.
Each request is launched only when previous is finished.
Very rarely do two in parallel.
`getmypid()` each time returns a new pid.

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is that the _entirety_ of the source code? You're not calling `session_start()` at _any_ point or otherwise opening a session?

Comment: @Sammitch this is the whole code.

Comment: Can you test that with something a bit more reliable and informational than hitting the `F5` key yourself on subsequent tabs in a browser session ? Something like [siege](https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/load-testing-and-benchmarking-with-siege/) should give you a much better overview (and might totally change your point of view).

Comment: @Zeitounator it happened on real project and has tested different ways, this is minimal working example